# JavaScript calling a function or chain method

Tags: javascript, sails.js

I'm currently working with SailsJS, and it has a built in "log". In this, you're able to:

```
sails.log('Default log');
```

Or:

```
sails.log.info('Info Log');
```

If I were to build a similar setup myself, how would I go about this? I've not really got any examples, since I'm not really sure how to even attempt it!

Comment: Since SailsJS it's OSS, have you checked how they are doing it?

Comment: "If I were to build a similar setup myself": are you asking us how you would go about building a Sails clone? Your question isn't clear.

Comment: They are just using a npm package that does that. It's called [captains-log](https://github.com/balderdashy/captains-log)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Javascript, You can declare a function

```
foo = function( a ){

   return console.log( a );

}
```

And then threat it as an object, and give it parameters. ( Even another function )

```
foo.bar = function( a ){

    console.info( a );

}
```

So now, You can use `foo( 9 );` and also `foo.bar( 9 );`

With this syntax, You can go as deep as You'd like, since You can also use foo.bar function as an object, and so on...

Comment: Pff damn I never thought you could do that - and there I was trying `eval()` and stuff!

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```js
function a(){
    alert(1);
}

a.b = function(){
    alert(2);
}

a();
a.b();
```

This is the most basic example, and executes just like how you expect.

Answer (score 1):

It's simple as soon as you realize that JavaScript functions are still regular objects, just acting in the presence of "()" operator. The above can be simply implemented e.g. like this:

```
function log (text) { console.log(text); }

log.info = function (infoText) { console.info(infoText); }
```